# Derive quadratic formula

Tags: quadratics, gre-exam

I cannot understand how quadratic formula to solve for $x$ was derived.

On this [website](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/sqrquad2.htm), it explains the steps

Following I understand

[image]

but I cannot understand how they got

$b/2a$

and why they are squaring it

$b^2/4a^2$

Really, I am baffled!

Comment: to complete the square $(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

This is the **completing the square** trick. Usefull in many other cases and simple to visualize.

[image]

The black square is $x^2$, the red rectangle is $bx$, so $x^2+bx$ can be transformed to a square adding the little blue square, that is $(b/2)^2$.

Comment: Honest to God, the concept still has to soak in. A picture is worth 1000 words.

Answer (score 6):

$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+K^2=(x+K)^2$

$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+K^2=x^2+2xK+K^2$

$\frac{b}{a}x=2xK$

$k=\frac{b}{2a}$

Then we know that

$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+(\frac{b}{2a})^2=(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2$

$x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2$

This process is called completing the square.
Now we can factor a perfect square. Is this answer sufficient?